# Call method of Parent page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have the 2 aspx pages as page 1 and page 2 . Page1 has button on which page2 will popup. where as page2 has button . the button click event on code behind of page 2, will call the method of page1 code behind. how this is possible ? please send me code line. please guide.
.

In Short:

how to call method from parent page code behind in child page code behind

Answer (score 0):

In the child page, you use syntax such as this:

```
window.opener.yourFunction();
```

Comment: is this name should be the name at code behind or javascript function

Comment: This would be in JavaScript. You won't be able to go from one aspx.cs to another aspx.cs directly, you'll need to interact with the parent page and trigger off a post-back.